# How to disable software raid (mdadm)?

Tags: ubuntu, software-raid

I have two 500GB hard disk that were in a software RAID1 on a gentoo distribution. Now I have put the on an Ubuntu Server 10.10 and they still want to be in a RAID. How do I disable the RAID.

sudo mdadm --detail /dev/dm-1
mdadm: /dev/dm-1 does not appear to be an md device

sudo mdadm --stop /dev/dm-1
mdadm: /dev/dm-1 does not appear to be an md device

> Device Boot      Start         End
>   Blocks   Id  System /dev/sdb1
>   1       60801   488384001   83  Linux
>
> Disk /dev/sdd: 500.1 GB, 500107862016
>   bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track,
>   60801 cylinders Units = cylinders of
>   16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes Sector
>   size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
>   512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal):
>   512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier:
>   0x00000000
>
> Device Boot      Start         End 
>   Blocks   Id  System /dev/sdd1
>   1       60801   488384001   83  Linux
>
> Disk /dev/sdc: 500.1 GB, 500107862016
>   bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track,
>   60801 cylinders Units = cylinders of
>   16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes Sector
>   size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
>   512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal):
>   512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier:
>   0x00000000
>
> Device Boot      Start         End 
>   Blocks   Id  System /dev/sdc1
>   1       60801   488384001   83  Linux
>
> Disk /dev/dm-1: 500.0 GB, 499999965184
>   bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track,
>   60788 cylinders Units = cylinders of
>   16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes Sector
>   size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
>   512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal):
>   512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier:
>   0x00000000
>
> ```
>  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
> ```
>
> /dev/dm-1p1               1
>   60801   488384001   83  Linux

Comment: Can you show the output of 'cat /proc/mdstat' ?

Comment: cat /proc/mdstat >> "
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
unused devices: <none>"

Comment: I think your disks know best.  They used to be together.. They *belong* together.  You can't just tear them apart.  Disks have feelings too, y'know.

Comment: @Tom overwrite the RAID superblock with a Converge song, drive will get over it better afterwards .... :)

Answer (score 4):

"**dmraid -rE**" did the trick. 
Removed the RAID array and everything is fine now.

Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 3):

You can make drives forget they were in a RAID by zeroing out their md superblocks. Assuming your old RAID drives are known as `/dev/sdc` and `/dev/sdd` in your Ubuntu system, try the following commands:

```
sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdc
sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdd
```

If, for whatever reason, those don't work, then you could try more drastic measures, like zeroing out the entire drives with `dd`, e.g.:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd
```

but I wouldn't try that unless nothing else worked, since it will take a relatively long time, **and it will delete all data on those drives.**

Comment: sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdc -->  mdadm: Couldn't open /dev/sdc for write - not zeroing

Comment: Will "sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc" make me lose data?

Comment: @user61888: Correct. The `dd` command will destroy all the data on the drive. If you want to keep your data, DO NOT do that.

Comment: @user61888: Try this: Run `sudo /etc/init.d/mdadm stop`, then try `sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdc` again.

Comment: Doesn't work either. It should be something from the harddisks themselves. They tried to be in a RAID array without me even installing mdadm.  When I disconnect one of them BIOS tells me that there's a problem, F1- to continue. Then I can use the connected disk normally. When I connect both HDs they become an array, FUUUUU...

Comment: @user61888: Your system's mobo or hd controller may have built-in ATA-RAID capability that Ubuntu detected during install, so it set up `dmraid`. If that is the case, it may be possible to disable the RAID capabilities in BIOS or the hd controller's firmware. Also, try `sudo dmraid -r` and/or `sudo dmraid -b` to see if `dmraid` is installed and has discovered your drives.

Comment: sudo dmraid -r --> 
"/dev/sdb: pdc, "pdc_ecehgh", mirror, ok, 976562432 sectors, data@ 0"   Yep, dmraid finds it. This is with only HD connected. How do I remove the RAID array now? dmraid -x pdc_ecehgh ? Will I loose data?

Comment: @user61888: Sorry, I don't know enough about `dmraid` to be much more helpful. Just curious, though: Do you actually have data on those drives that you need to recover? If so, how were you planning to do that?